# Return the function input if it extends the generic type, otherwise null

Tags: typescript

I am trying to type up a filter function which takes a generic parameter and enforces that the return type of the function given is either the input if it matches the generic or `null` if not.

```
type A = { type: 'A' };
type B = { type: 'B' };

type Union = A | B;
const filter = <T extends Union>(filter: <E extends Union>(item: E) => E extends T ? E : null) => {
  // something
};

filter<A>((item) => { 
// Argument of type '<E extends Union>(item: E) => E | null' is not assignable to parameter of type '<E extends Union>(item: E) => E extends A ? E : null'. 
// Type 'E | null' is not assignable to type 'E extends A ? E : null'. 
// Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'E extends A ? E : null'.(2345)
  if (item.type === 'A') return item;

  return null;
});
```

I do not quite understand why this is not working. I suppose the error message is a bit misleading, I suspect TS does not understand that `if (item.type === 'A') return item;` actually satisfies the `E extends A ? E` part?

I suppose I could also use a type guard, but this would not enforce that all types of `T` will be returned.

[Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeVSQFxQOQy1AvgNwCwAUGtAEILKrgSZaV5FlkVQCqAdgJYD23GnAA+USiVIBjQQGdgUAGa8ANsAgAnGgB4AKlAgAPddwAmsrn0EA+ABTK1mzNoCiB4xDMWeA7nd7qALaYLgCUCNZQbkYm5lD6APxRUJjcAK4qKuHwkUhkUFAA9IVQsvyBEMAAFrzcAOZkrKRszaQO6hraMHa2ARCB2bn5ULyKUL1BAHQc8LPYuOEalWkaQn2BksNLwCtC6ZmS+KGEQA)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure to understand why the return type of the `filter` function has to be `E extends T ? E : null`. There is a condition in it, not sure this is allowed.

This simplified version does compile:

```
type A = { type: 'A' };
type B = { type: 'B' };

type Union = A | B;
const filter = (filter: <E extends Union>(item: E) => E | null) => {
  // something
};



filter((item) => {
  if (item.type === 'A') return item;

  return null;
});
```

Comment: Right, it does not need to be `E extends T ...` but I want to ensure that it returns `item` only if it fits the type passed in as `T` and `null` or something else I can discern otherwise.